# YIi Active Record selecting fixed fields

Tags: yii

I am using Active Record queries like below for fetching records but query below selects all possible columns. I wanted to select only 2 columns ( firstname, lastname )

```
Profile::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>'1'))
```

To select only firstname below works, how can I add also lastname to SELECT in statement **without** using a CDBCriteria.

```
$first = Profile::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_id'=>'1'))->firstname
```

Second, I have also used relations to lazy load records as and when needed , there also SELECTING fields that are only needed will improve the performance overall.

Comment: why are you avoiding CDBCriteria? with use of CDBCriteria, you can get selected columns easily..

Comment: Such code are throughout the code , and adding a criteria would be neat as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using CDBCriteria, you can do as below

```
$first=Profile::model()->find(array(
    'select'=>'firstname,lastname',
    'condition'=>'user_id=:uid',
    'params'=>array(':uid'=>1),
));
```